# Find games involving player

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

In my models there is a many to many relation ship between games and users. How can I find all the games involving a given player?

I tried `Game.all(Game.users.include?(u))` but got a `NoMethodError` about `include?`

---

Here are my models per http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html

```
class User
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,         Serial

    has n, :games, :through => Resource
end

class Game
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,         Serial

    has n, :users, :through => Resource
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an instance of a user u, then what you want is u.games.all.  Each user has a set of games.  I assume it is the games they are playing.